# How to animate parent height auto when children height is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I have a parent `div` with height set to `auto`.

Now whenever I fade something in that's a child of that `div`, the height just jumps to the new height. I want this to be a smooth transition.

The height is supposed to transition **before** any children are being displayed, and also transition **after** any children are being removed (`display: none;`).

I know this is possible when you know the predefined heights, but I have no idea how I can achieve this with the height being set to `auto`.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Hg9s/1/)

Comment: Do the possible child elements of your parent DIV have known heights, or is their height given by their content? And is there always only one child visible at the time or several?

Comment: The possible child elements have no known heights. The height is indeed given by their content. And yes, there is always one child visible at least.

Comment: OK, so you have to determine the height of the appropriate child **before** you may transition the height of the parent. How about an alternative approach: Set the parent height to zero and transition its height with the child already visible? Would be much easier and imho the "nicer" effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load new content with `display: none` and `slideDown()` it in and then fadeIn with animated opacity. Before you remove it you just fade out and `slideUp()`

I think this is what you wanted: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/3Hg9s/17/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").click(function() {
        if($("#bar").is(":visible")) {
            $("#bar").animate({"opacity": 0}, function() {
                $(this).slideUp();
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#bar").css({
                "display": "none",
                "opacity": 0,
                /* The next two rows are just to get differing content */
                "height": 200 * Math.random() + 50,
                "background": "rgb(" + Math.round(255 * Math.random()) + "," + Math.round(255 * Math.random()) + "," + Math.round(255 * Math.random()) + ")"
            });
            $("#bar").slideDown(function() {
                $(this).animate({"opacity": 1});
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Try this also: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/3Hg9s/14/). Click "Click me" to add new divs. Click on a new div to remove it.

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").click(function() {
        var newCont = $("<div>").css({
            "display": "none",
            "opacity": 0,
            "height": 200 * Math.random(),
            "background": "rgb(" + Math.round(255 * Math.random()) + "," + Math.round(255 * Math.random()) + "," + Math.round(255 * Math.random()) + ")"
        });
        $(this).append(newCont);
        newCont.slideDown(function() {
            $(this).animate({"opacity": 1});
        });
        newCont.click(function(e) {
            $(this).animate({"opacity": 0}, function() {
                $(this).slideUp(function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think this one should be it. 1 question though, why are you using opacity and not fadeOut / fadeIn? Just curious.

Comment: @KidDiamond That is because fadeOut will add `display: none` at the end, collapsing the parent div. With animated opacity I can use slideUp and down to collapse. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/xq8WF/

Answer (score 1):

The approach I took was to see if `.bar` was visible, and if so fade it out, the animate the height of `#foo` back to where it started, or animating it to the height of `.bar` + `#foo` otherwise, using callbacks in both cases to get the effect that you were looking for.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    var start_height = $('#foo').outerHeight();
    $("#foo").click(function() {
        $bar = $('.bar');
        $foo = $(this);
        if($bar.is(':visible')) {
            $bar.fadeToggle('slow', function() {
                $foo.animate({height: start_height});
            });
        } else {
            $foo.animate({height: ($bar.outerHeight()+start_height)+'px'}, 'slow', function() {
                $bar.fadeToggle();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3Hg9s/5/)

**EDIT:**

Added `.stop()` to prevent unexpected behavior when double clicked.

[Updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3Hg9s/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use developer tools in browsers.

All browser have nowadays it. (ctrl shift i)

If u look at page source code after fadeOut executed, u will see inline style "display:none" for inner element. This means that your inner element has no height any more, that is why outer(parent) element collapsed (height =0);

It is a feature of all browsers, that block elements take height as they need unless u will not override it. so since there are no elements inside with height more than 0 px that height of parent will be 0px;

y can override it using css style

```
height: 300px  
or
min-height: 300px;
```

This is correct if u use jquery

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. It's not particularly about fading out elements, but rather having a smooth height transition whenever it is modified (bigger or smaller) with `height: auto`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix :)

```
 $(function() {
    var height =  $("#foo").height();
    $("#foo").click(function() {  
     var dis =   $(".bar").css('display');

     if(dis == 'none'){
      $(this).animate({height:height+$(".bar").height()},2000,function(){
      $(".bar").show();
       });
     } 
      else{
        $(".bar").hide();
        $(this).animate({height:height-$(".bar").height()},2000);
       }

    });
});

#foo {
    height: auto;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    min-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution to my issue. The height is supposed to transition before the children are being displayed, and transition after the children are hidden. Furthermore, your code keeps on adding height.

Comment: Okay nice. Getting closer to it. When you click real fast continuously the height and animation starts getting really glitchy.

Comment: Its jQuery api's behaviour if you keep on clicking real fast continously.I think this is not the defect as no one will click like this.